# How to set an object to the updated value returned by Angular $resource?

Tags: angularjs, rest

How do you save an object to a `$resource` and then set the object to the API response value returned by the `$resource`?

I have an object, `value` (which is part of an array of objects I am iterating through), that I save to a ReST API.

When the save is successful, the API responds with same object, plus any extra details such as the object's id (if the save was a create) or perhaps the file paths that the back end saved to. Stuff the front end can't know about until the back end adds it.

I want to update the saved `value` object with those extra details returned in the `response`, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have tried returning the response from the `$resource` callbacks, but I can't make it work. It returns a `$$state` object (which I don't know what to do with) rather than the response. I may be doing that wrong.

In any case I would rather set the `value` object to the `response` object inside the success callback, because I only want to set the object to the response when the save is successful, not when there's an error.

But I don't know how to pass the `value` object to the callback to be updated, which is the crux of my problem.

(And I can't figure out how search the array for the object from inside the callback because the `$resource` success response doesn't include the `$$hashkey`. Only the error response includes the `$$hashkey`. This approach seems like a kludge to me anyway)

Here is the basic pattern I am trying to use. I'm hoping someone will point out the flaw with the pattern, or show me how to pass `value` to the callbacks, or whatever. Ideally I'd like to know what the best practice pattern is for saving objects to a $resource and immediately updating them with the response data.

(`Resource` is the name I have given in this example to an Angular factory that returns a $resource object.)

```
  function success(response) {
    //I want to set value to response here, but value is out of scope
    //so instead I do this but it returns $$state rather than response
    return response;
  }
  function error(response) {
    Status.reportError(response);
  }

  value = Resource.create(value)
   .$promise.then(success, error);
```

I imagine I could find `value` somewhere in the `$scope` of the callback (?) but I'm trying avoid using `$scope` due to its pending deprecation.

Thanks in advance

Jay Dee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
Resource.create(value, function(success) {
   value.id = success.id;//depends on what you return, may be success.data.id or similar
}, function(error) {});
```